# codegear(c++) and serial port

Tags: c++, serial-port, c++builder

Can anybody help me find free components or any other easy way to communicate with device attached to the serial port? I'm using Codegear and quite desperate after few days of googling.

Answer (score 0):

[boost](http://www.boost.org/).[asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/asio/index.html) has support for serial ports:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using old Borland C++ resources, are compatible with embarcadero.

http://maikel.galeon.com/serie/bcbcomm.html

http://denkovi.com/denkovi-bcb-com-port-tool

Codegear is also compatible with delphi libraries
http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/